# PostGIS: Two equal geometries are not equal?

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis

I have two geometries in different tables which look like the same, but one is valid and the other is invalid. I checked it out:

```sql
select  ST_IsValid(_s.geom) as _gvalid, 
        ST_IsValid(s.geom) as gvalid,
        _s.geom = s.geom as  geom_bin_equal, 
        ST_SRID(_s.geom)=ST_SRID(s.geom) as srid_equal, 
        ST_EQUALS(_s.geom, s.geom), 
        ST_AsText(_s.geom) = ST_AsText(s.geom) as text_equal 
from _spatial_object _s, spatial_object s
where _s.id_spatial_object = 314 and s.id_spatial_object = 314
```

Output here:

[image]

How on the earth it could be?

Actually, the both geometries should be invalid (Interior is disconnected at or near point 58.182000000000002 51.457000000000001)

Geometry:

POLYGON((58.169 51.456,58.176 51.458,58.18 51.458,58.182 51.457,58.183 51.456,58.182 51.453,58.184 51.451,58.182 51.449,58.183 51.448,58.181 51.445,58.179 51.443,58.177 51.444,58.179 51.445,58.178 51.446,58.178 51.448,58.178 51.448,58.177 51.448,58.173 51.447,58.17 51.449,58.173 51.45,58.174 51.451,58.178 51.451,58.178 51.452,58.178 51.452,58.176 51.452,58.173 51.451,58.169 51.456),(58.169 51.456,58.1732222222222 51.4569444444444,58.182 51.457,58.169 51.456))

```
select ST_ISValid(geom), ST_IsValid(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(geom))) from _spatial_object
```

outputs

true false

Comment: As a rule of thumb, never work with invalid geometries as some (most?) functions will return unreliable results.

Comment: Which version of PostGIS are you using? the definition of `=` [changed](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Geometry_EQ.html) in version 2.4 (from bounding box equality to exact equality)

Comment: @JGH POSTGIS="2.1.8 r13780" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4090" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" RASTER

Comment: Ah, that's it then, I will add an answer

Comment: My main concern is that the validation gives the false result

Comment: well, that addresses the question (equal but not equal). Without seeing the geometry, it is impossible to tell why it is (or not) invalid.

Comment: @JGH Edited the question, added geometry.

Comment: The difference between the `st_isvalid` tests is that the 1st one use the true coordinates while the 2nd one rounds to 15 decimals when converting to text. You may want to use `st_snapToGrid` to set the points to a meaningful coordinate precision

Comment: @JGH Thanks for the comment about rounding when converting from text. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to version 2.4, the equality using `=` was relying on a bounding box comparison only, so two very different geometries could still be considered as being equal.

When using [`ST_Equals`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Equals.html), the two geometries must "look" the same (but the vertices order does not matter). However, the doc notes that

> [Important]
>
> This function will return false if either geometry is invalid except
> in the case where they are binary equal.

but also  mentions that

> Changed: 2.2.0 Returns true even for invalid geometries if they are
> binary equal

So because you are using an older version, the result is unreliable / false.